# Writing to a text file while making use of Multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, writetofile

I'm trying to have a dedicated thread that periodically overwrites a file such that the only thing that actually changes in the file is something that I've changed in the GUI. Here is the relevant Code:

```
    private ThreadClass writeToFile = new ThreadClass("toFile"){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            synchronized(lock){
                NameAddressID store[] = new NameAddressID[10];
                boolean tmpFile = true;
                Scanner loadOver;
                PrintWriter overWrite;
                while(true){

                    try {
                        if(tmpFile){
                            loadOver = new Scanner(new File("NAIList.txt"));
                            overWrite = new PrintWriter("NAIList.tmp", "UTF-8");
                        }else{
                            loadOver = new Scanner(new File("NAIList.tmp"));
                            overWrite = new PrintWriter("NAIList.txt", "UTF-8");
                        }
                        for(int i = 0; i < count-1; i++){
                            for(int j = 0; j<10; j++){
                                if(loadOver.hasNextLine()){
                                    String[] tokens = loadOver.nextLine().split(";");
                                        store[j] = new NameAddressID(tokens[0], tokens[1], tokens[2], tokens[3], tokens[4], tokens[5], Integer.valueOf(tokens[6]), Integer.valueOf(tokens[7]));
                                }else{
                                    store[j] = null;
                                }
                            }
                            for(int j = 0; j<store.length;j++){
                                if(store[j] != null){
                                    overWrite.print(store[j].getFirst()+";");
                                    System.out.print(store[j].getFirst()+" ");
                                    overWrite.print(store[j].getMiddle()+";");
                                    System.out.print(store[j].getMiddle()+" ");
                                    overWrite.print(store[j].getLast()+";");
                                    System.out.print(store[j].getLast()+" ");
                                    overWrite.print(store[j].getStreet()+";");
                                    System.out.print(store[j].getStreet()+" ");
                                    overWrite.print(store[j].getCity()+";");
                                    System.out.print(store[j].getCity()+" ");
                                    overWrite.print(store[j].getState()+";");
                                    System.out.print(store[j].getState()+" ");
                                    overWrite.print(store[j].getZip()+";");
                                    System.out.print(store[j].getZip()+" ");
                                    overWrite.println(store[j].getId());
                                    System.out.println(store[j].getId());
                                    store[j] = null;
                                    overWrite.flush();
                                }else{
                                    break;
                                }
                            }

                        }
                        saveArrayText("NAIList.tmp", overWrite);
                        for(int i = 0; i < addressList.size(); i++){
                            if(loadOver.hasNextLine()){
                                String skip = loadOver.nextLine();
                            }
                        }
                        while(loadOver.hasNextLine()){
                            int index = 0;
                            String[] tokens = loadOver.nextLine().split(";");
                            store[index++] = new NameAddressID(tokens[0], tokens[1], tokens[2], tokens[3], tokens[4], tokens[5], Integer.valueOf(tokens[6]), Integer.valueOf(tokens[7]));
                            for(int j = 0; j<store.length;j++){
                                if(store[j] != null){
                                    overWrite.print(store[j].getFirst()+";");
                                    overWrite.print(store[j].getMiddle()+";");
                                    overWrite.print(store[j].getLast()+";");
                                    overWrite.print(store[j].getStreet()+";");
                                    overWrite.print(store[j].getCity()+";");
                                    overWrite.print(store[j].getState()+";");
                                    overWrite.print(store[j].getZip()+";");
                                    overWrite.println(store[j].getId());
                                    store[j] = null;
                                    overWrite.flush();
                                    break;
                                }
                            }   
                        }
                        tmpFile = !tmpFile;
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    lock.notifyAll();
                    System.out.println("Saved");
                    try {
                        lock.wait();
                        Thread.sleep(60000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

I know that it reaches the for loop where I take all of the elements in store[] and write them to a file, and it does print the correct data to the console. However, any time it modifies either NAIList.txt or NAIList.tmp, it just makes them completely blank. I have no clue why it isn't working since the code is essentially copied from a different method run on the main thread that did work as I wanted it to.

Ah, forgot to add, as an artificial limitation that my teacher gave us, we are only allowed to have Ten `NameAddressID` objects in the RAM at any given time.

EDIT: Fixed code, only thing that changed is that `overWrite.flush();` was added twice

Comment: Try and separate your code into logical units first. You can pass arguments to implementations of `Runnable`, you know... And also, Java has locking objects which may help. In short: divide and conquer. As it is, your code is barely manageable, but I believe I need not even tell you that.

Comment: Flush the stream every time you done editing.

Comment: Ah, my mistake, I will try that now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't you need to flush the PrintWriter?

See the PrintWriter constructor's javadoc:

> Creates a new PrintWriter, **without automatic line flushing**, with the
>   specified file. This convenience constructor creates the necessary
>   intermediate OutputStreamWriter, which will encode characters using
>   the default charset for this instance of the Java virtual machine.